# Question on ValueState for KeyedStream and List State for operator from the checkpoint view

Tags: apache-flink

For the operator state, for example, `ListState`, It uses CheckpointedFunction's `snapshotState` and `initializeState` to save state or restore state.That means, it is working closely with Flink's checkpoint mechanism.

But for the operator working on the KeyStream, for example,KeyedProcessFunction , In  KeyedProcessFunction's processElement method, it works directly with ValueState's value() and update() method to get or update state. Does it work correctly coded in this way? Take a replayable source for example, if the source is replayed from the last checkpoint due to task failure, the processElement method will process some duplicate records, so that the ValueState may not be quite right because it may update more than once for the duplicate key, I think the ValueState should also get back to the state of last checkpoint, that means, ValueState should also work with the checkpoint mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both non-keyed and keyed state are checkpointed, and both are restored during a restart. ValueState is automatically checkpointed, as is MapState, and timers, and broadcast state. (And ListState when it is used as a kind of keyed state.)

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson. That means, when I call `ValueState's update` method in the processElement, it actually write to the local storage area, and the local storaged state will be written to remote persistent stoage during checkpoint phrase?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So when I use RocksDB and I have KeyedProcessFunction with Value state, every call to state.update(...) in processElement mehtod is flushed/serialized to local disk?

Is there any way to update the state only during checkpoint? Something like when we use CheckpointedFunction interface on my KeyedProcessFunction implementation?

Comment: State updates are written into an in-memory memtable, which is written to disk as an SST file when it is full. The memtables are flushed to disk during checkpointing (to ensure the checkpoint is complete), but not with every update.